# Deleted accepted answer pinned as top answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481725/with-block-equivalent-in-c), the accepted answer (with 23 votes) is deleted. But it is still pinned to the top.
(10k required to see deleted answer)

[image]

By the looks of it, the answer was deleted from the "low quality posts" review queue. But it never got unpinned when upon deletion.

Comment: Though certainly reasonable, it's not obvious to me that deletion should outweigh acceptance and votes for sorting pruposes.  Are you sure this isn't by design?

Comment: Deleted answers are always below the undeleted ones regardless of votes (even deleted accepted answers). This is the first time I've seen it the other way.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yep. And if I view it while logged out, the answer disappears as usual. So it doesn't appear to break anything for sub-10ks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears there was a time when deleting an answer *didn't* remove that checkmark - and this answer was deleted then.

Undeleting it and re-deleting it causes it to sort correctly at the bottom, sans checkmark.

Comment: I just realized that the deletion date was before the review-beta queues. So what deleted it?

Comment: No idea. Lost in the mists of time, no doubt.