# Purging a user account does not unaccept its accepted answers

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, deleted-answers, deleted-accounts

There seems to be some magical wand movement that permits mods to send a user account and all its posts into oblivion.<sup>1</sup>

Normally, according to [Shog9's answer to Deleted accepted answer pinned as top answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148507), deleting an accepted answer should also unaccept it. However, this fails with answers deleted by magical wand.

**Link to answer:** https://superuser.com/a/502083 (requires 10k rep on SU)

**Screenshot:** [image: screenshot]

The answers acts as accepted for all purposes, meaning that it stays on top of the others answers when sorted by votes, and the questions appears as having an accepted answer in the OP's profile.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>At least that is what I suppose happens when a post appears just as *deleted*, not *deleted by*.</sub>

Comment: We call it nuking from orbit.  It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: That's magical.

Comment: Does it really matter? If the OP of the question comes back they can accept another answer and that will move the mark. (As an aside what I'd really like as a 20k user is the ability to hide deleted answers).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think you're on the wrong site for [that...](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/1118)

Comment: @ChrisF: Hardly a matter of life and death, but it might be a minor setback for people searching for questions with accepted answers. The user script [Stack Overflow - Deleted Answer Manager](http://stackapps.com/q/3408) can hide deleted answers. ALl you have to do is add your non-SO sites and set the behavior to somehting else that *hide answers, but show their content* (doesn't make a lot of sense).