# How did an accepted answer get deleted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

I was looking through a list of wpf questions with 0 answers and found this one:

[WPF TreeView with IsVirtualizing="true" jumps around when changing focus and scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930154/wpf-treeview-with-isvirtualizing-true-jumps-around-when-changing-focus-and-scr)

The caveat here is that in the list, it showed 0 answers but had the markup as if one of the 0 answers was accepted. Intrigued, I clicked and discovered that this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931696/1026459 (10k+ req to view) had been deleted.

The deleted answer was accepted (although it is not very high quality). Or the accepted answer was deleted. One of the two happened, but I was not sure how. I tried it on one of my own accepted answers and was denied with the message "You cannot delete this accepted answer".

How did the linked accepted answer get deleted?

Comment: I'm not quite sure *how* it got deleted, but it definitely deserved to be deleted.

Comment: @animuson - I think it did too. It just stood out to me as an oddity. I was actually curious from the standpoint of, if it were possible that two answers could then be accepted on that question.

Comment: It had to have been deleted by some sort of automated process, because there's no deletion event in the history. There's also no flags on it or any other sort of activity in the post's timeline.

Comment: @animuson - I think this might be a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148502/178816 (note that the deleted answer from this other meta post was deleted on the same exact day of the one I just posted). Perhaps a script can be ran to undelete and re-delete all deleted answers from that day or from the action which deleted those answers?

Comment: The accepted answer deletion restriction doesn’t apply if the question is self-answered (like this one)… I think.

Comment: @minitech - The answer I attempted to delete was a self-answered answer. It would not let me. I can understand how it could be hard to test from your end though, because as Robert notes, since you are a mod you can delete accepted answers.